I can't remember an animated movie
The movie looks like it is from the 90's. It is animated, I'm not sure if it's Disney.
It has two children - a boy and a girl- who are possibly orphans. They receive  help from two adults - a guy with orange-brown hair and a blonde girl (I think). The children get kidnapped by an evil man who has a scary house and a long beard. the boy gets trapped on his way escaping, to something that looks like a bear claw trap, there is a dog tied to a leash who barks at the boy.
In the beginning of the movie, there is a train station. They sing songs. That's all I can remember. 

The Rescuers perhaps? That's about orphans.

In an abandoned river boat in Devil's Bayou, a young orphan named Penny drops a message in a bottle containing a plea for help into the river. The bottle washes up in New York City, where it is recovered by the Rescue Aid Society, an international mouse organization inside the United Nations. The Hungarian representative, Miss Bianca, volunteers to accept the case and chooses Bernard, a stammering janitor, as her co-agent. The two visit Morningside Orphanage, where Penny lived, and meet an old cat named Rufus. He tells them about a woman named Madame Medusa who once tried to lure Penny into her car and may have succeeded in abducting Penny this time.





Can you please elaborate on why you think it fits the specific details mentioned in the question? A huge amount of Disney movies are about orphans...

Hi, the characters were human. It was a little girl and boy I think. They were trapped in a scary house by an evil man with a long dark beard. They had two adult figures who helped them. The adult figures became love interests later on. The drawings were similar to Anastasia. Thanks for the help.

Thanks Okanya. But I was actually asking Clare to elaborate on her answer...

It's Babes In Toyland. I have been searching for it for so long and I found it. Here's a link to the movie 



